# UIView Animation won't run transition

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview

So, I've searched quite a bit for this and can't seem to find a solution.

This code works:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
[c setCenter:CGPointMake(200, 200)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This code doesn't:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:context];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:c cache:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];
[c exchangeSubviewAtIndex:0 withSubviewAtIndex:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And I know the call to exchangeSubViewAtIndex is working because if I remove it from the animation block it functions as expected.

Anyone have any insight as to why this transition won't run? Something I need to import?

Comment: The "context" argument is for use by an animation callback (setAnimationDelegate/setAnimationWillStartSelector/setAnimationDidStopSelector). You don't need it. Set it to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll quote Apple (again) here:

> If you want to change the appearance of a view during a transition—for example, flip from one view to another—then use a container view, an instance of UIView, as follows:
>
> 1. Begin an animation block.
> 2. Set the transition on the container view.
> 3. Remove the subview from the container view.
> 4. Add the new subview to the container view.
> 5. Commit the animation block.

So you probably would like to use `removeFromSuperview` & `addSubView:` instead of exchanging two subviews if you were using a predefined transition.

Comment: Yeah, that's the pattern I followed. And I get the same result from remove and add as opposed to exchanging.